# Invalid code signing entitlements - specifically value 'dns-proxy' for key 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension'

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working an existing app on the App Store. The only thing I have to do is update the splash screen and icon.

However, when I try to upload iTunes Store I get the error:
"Invalid code signing entitlements - specifically value 'dns-proxy' for key 'com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension' in 'Payload/AppName.app/AppName' is not supported."

I'm new to building IOS apps - can someone please point in the right direction to fix this?

Comment: Any news I am facing he same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the Network Extensions capability, which seems to only appear in Xcode 8.3.3, for all related targets in the Capabilities Tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. Go to the You Apps on Apple Developer.
2. Go to your Idetifiers (App IDS) and uncheck Network Extensions.
3. Try again to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to update your developer certificate in your XCode and patch it again.Try to validate it before you upload it.